# HTML5 history APi

Tags: html, pushstate

How do i use HTML5 history api. I did go through the https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history. That confused me. All that i want is to change the url on ajax calls so that when user hits the back button he gets the previous state.

Also i wnat to know of any pit falls of this . When to use and when not to use.  How best to use with jquery

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here are the best resources which I've come across (including the one you already mentioned, and a working code example):

- [MDC: Manipulating the Browser History](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history) - very basic native example
- [Dive into HTML5: Manipulating the HTML5 History API for Fun and Profit](http://fortuito.us/diveintohtml5/history.html) - good intro
- [Intelligent State Handling:](https://github.com/balupton/History.js/wiki/Intelligent-State-Handling) - article about hashbangs VS hashes VS HTML5 History API - provides working code solutions.
- [Ajaxify a Website with the HTML5 History API using History.js and ScrollTo](https://gist.github.com/854622) - working code example

In regards to pitfalls give the "Intelligent State Handling" link a good read. In regards to backwards compatibility there is [History.js](https://github.com/balupton/history.js) which fixes the browsers bugs and provides an optional HTML4 hash fallback.

Answer (score 3):

I think the free online book [Dive into HTML5](http://fortuito.us/diveintohtml5/) is generally an excellent source for a description of the new features of HTLM5. It has a chapter about the new history element, [Manipulating History for Fun & Profit](http://fortuito.us/diveintohtml5/history.html).

The executive summary is that it is not just a online-liner to make this work correctly. When you fake loading a new page using AJAX you also have to fake loading the previous page when the user clicks on the back button.

Comment: oh so i only have to load the previous page is it it wont do auto matically as in re send the ajax request

Comment: I should mention the book edition by O'Reilly (HTML5 Up and Running) does not have that chapter, if you were hoping to read it offline.