# Multiple site/url integration with same header that doesn't reload when clicking to other sites

Tags: jquery, url, static, header, masking

I can't seem to wrap my head around this one, and if it can be done I'll be overjoyed.  I'm building a website for a friend's film company, and he requested that there be a header on the top of each specific film site that links to each other film site with the film names.  The header is the exact same on each film site with the exact placement.  Each film site also resides on a different URL, and not subdirectories in the same URL.

Now he also requested that the header NOT refresh when clicking to other sites.  I'm wondering if this is possible, and I'm totally open to the possibility of having all sites reside on the same URL in separate directories.  He also wants the URL of each site to be visible, so not just loading content for each site in the same site and not having the URL in the browser change as well.

The company URL is www.breakwaterstudios.com

The first film URL is www.dinnerwithfred.com

The second film URL is www.inkandpapermovie.com

(I haven't yet integrated the new header on the sites).

However, if the only way to go about doing this is to have the URLs be

www.breakwaterstudios.com/dinnerwithfred

www.breakwaterstudios.com/inkandpapermovie

And then have the individual URLs redirect to those subdirectories that's fine.

The only way I can figure that I could go about not having the page reload when clicking on each header button is to

1) Code the entirety of all film sites into each individual film site and have each individual film site load its respective site elements first (hiding the other sites' elements).  HOWEVER, this would need some sort of javascript/Ajax URL change/rewrite code or something to mask the fact that each film site is really coded into the same site and it's just reloading using jquery .show and .hide commands.  And it could take a long time to load all the other sites' content in the same index.html file.

2) Use jquery .load or iframes even to dynamically load each site underneath the header when clicking on the header buttons.  However, the URL would need to be rewritten just like number 1.

3) As the header div will be in the same position on all sites, and if the only way to get this to work is to reload to the page, have the header not flash off when another film site loads on a separate or same URL.  Have the header appear to not reload when in fact it's loading on a separate website.  There's a fraction of a second where the header disappears and reappears when clicking to another site.

The part of this that seems difficult is the whole URL change.

I suppose what I'm getting at is the possibility of retaining the header on each site without reloading the header when going to each site.  I see that Facebook can do this, however it's all within the same URL of facebook.com.  I've done research and found that perhaps it's impossible across multiple URLs due to the potential of security risks/masking/fraud/etc.

The jquery .load function and iframe could work, but the URL would need to be changed, and if the entirely of the URL can't be changed from dinnerwithfred.com to inkandpapermovie.com, then at least the subdirectory change in the browser window.

Any help would be GREATLY appreciated!!!  Thanks!!!

- Dillon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On modern Browsers you could use the HTML5 history API:

- http://diveintohtml5.info/history.html
- [HTML5 history APi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5368605/html5-history-api)

I think there are some hacks for older browsers as well.
But as you said i think it only works on the same domain. So you'll be stuck with subdirectory urls here.
As for loading the pages itself i think iFrames are really your best bet.

You could also grab the page with http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/ for example if you really want to integrate the pages in yours. It's probably not that easy though to extract the content correctly. There may also be legal issues with that (since you don't own the other sites, do you?)

Comment: This is great!!  Thank you!  I'm reading about the HTML5 history API on the divintohtml5 site and it's really informative.  I'll report back on the success of implementing this API into my sites.  Fortunately I do own the other sites as well, so all elements are mine, so won't have to worry about that.  Thanks again!  And thanks for your quick response too - I love this site!

Comment: Unfortunately I'm having some difficulty implementing the code.  If the site is organized like

www.breakwaterstudios.com/index.html
www.breakwaterstudios.com/dinnerwithfred/index.html
www.breakwaterstudios.com/inkandpaper/index.html

is it even possible to use the History API?  It would be calling the index.html on multiple subdirectories - not just index1.html, index2.html, etc.  When loading in the content into the div it is breaking all embedded links as it's looking for /images rather than /dinnerwithfred/images folder (not looking in the subdirectory)...

Comment: Can it work with multiple subdomains?  How would the code reference these subdomains if all the examples of History API are only looking for small snippets of code instead of loading an entire website?  Because all the websites have folders in their root directory - images, css, etc. the History API is breaking the links as it's bringing the site from www.breakwaterstudios.com/dinnerwithfred to www.breakwaterstudios.com.  For example, and image linked at www.breakwaterstudios.com/dinnerwithfred/images/picture.jpg is loading as www.breakwaterstudios.com/images/picture.jpg.  Thanks for any help!